# Edit a field with a "Required" rule

Tags: infopath, list-form

I have a form made in InfoPath to create material requests at my office. One of these fields is a Choice Type with two options: *Department* and *Project*, this Choice Type is required. There is also a second Choice Type that becomes required if the previous one is *Project*. I have implemented this behaviour using an InfoPath rule.

Once an item is created I can edit it by a very similar form, which has the same fields of the creation form as well as some extra fields generated authomatically. (which I did not implement).

The problem is that on this form I can't change the first field from Department to Project or viceversa because there is no other option and I can't turn it back to blank because it has to be a required field.

Answer (score 0):

First, the field you want to become required if some condition was selected can't be required in the column configuration and needs to have a blank value by default, this topic can help you to set a blank value by default in your column:

[How to Add Blank to choice field?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19076/how-to-add-blank-to-choice-field)

Open your InfoPath Designer and select the desired list.

Select the field that you want to become required if "Project" was selected.

Go to properties tab > Manage rules

On manage rules window, click "New" > "Validation"

Create a new condition for this rule, something like:

if "required field" equals to "Project"

Then click OK

So the field will be only required if the required field value is "Project"

Hope it helps.