# Creating a Sharepoint 2013 List with multiple rows under one column header using InfoPath 2013

Tags: 2013, list, infopath

I want to create an order form with 14 columns and as many rows as possible that will kick off a workflow. my challenge is creating a single List at one go to contain an X amount of rows with a single row of column headings(14) to be saved as a single list and can be editted later.

i am very new on infopath and still finding my way around sharepoint. please asisst.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As SharePoint's list includes the built-in `Title` column, which is always a *required* field, no blank entries can be added to a list. Therefore you'd need to be populating the list with entries which add content to each field which is required. An input of "This is a placeholder" can do it for you, but possibly a "blank" input (as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/19267/21441)) does the job too.

Comment: Hi, thanks but i want to be able to able multiple roows to a single list. is that possible using infopath?

Comment: I want to be able to only insert the text field when i click on "insert item" not the hander and field. i want the list to be tabulated and then stored as a single list on sharepoint lists. is that possible?